# How to merge the specific commit changes from one brach to another without manual effort

Tags: bitbucket

Can any body sugest what is the best way to avoid the manual effort while moving the code from one branch to another.

follow is my scenario.

1. developers will perform multiple commits to develop branch from their local.
2. once the code integration done and testing done successfully, developer intent to move his/her code to QA branch, but meanwhile there are other developers will also do their commit.
3. now i would like to skip others commits and want to move specific changes to QA so is there a way to make this happen smothly without loosing anybodys code.